# JMETER Beanshell Read File - Not working - Getting Error Command not found: newBufferedReader( java.io.FileReader )

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-5.0

Below is my complete code that I entered in Jmeter BeanShell Sampler.

```
BufferedReader fileReader = newBufferedReader(new FileReader("F:/url.txt"));
int counter = 1;
content = fileReader.readLine();
while ((nextLine = fileReader.readLine()) != null)
{
content = content + "\n" + nextLine;
counter++;
}
vars.put("content",content);
```

I am getting below error when I try to execute, I can see this error in log.info

```
2019-12-02 11:38:01,431 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``BufferedReader fileReader = newBufferedReader(new FileReader("F:/url.txt")); int . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Command not found: newBufferedReader( java.io.FileReader )
2019-12-02 11:38:01,432 WARN o.a.j.p.j.s.BeanShellSampler: Exception executing script. org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``BufferedReader fileReader = newBufferedReader(new FileReader("F:/url.txt")); int . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Command not found: newBufferedReader( java.io.FileReader )
```

I just copy pasted this code from online examples and similarly I tried so many different option to read a file, but it's not working, could someone please help me.

I am using windows machine and jmeter version 5.1

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code, you need to change this:

```
newBufferedReader
```

to this:

```
new newBufferedReader
```

as the instantiation assumes using Java [`new` operator](https://www.javatpoint.com/new-keyword-in-java)

---

P.S. [Since JMeter 3.1 users are recommended to user JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), the reasons are in:

- Groovy has better performance than Beanshell
- Groovy is more modern language which supports all new Java features while with Beanshell you're stuck at [Java 1.5 language level](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/grid/java-5-features-083037.html)
- Groovy provides [a lot of enhancements](https://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html) over normal Java SDK

assuming all above you can convert your code to this:

```
vars.put("content", new File("F:/urls.txt").text)
```

P.P.S. It is also recommended to avoid scripting where possible and use JMeter's built-in components for maximum performance so if you only need to read a file into a JMeter Variable you can consider using [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) like:

```
${__FileToString(F:/urls.txt,,content)}
```

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction/) article for more information on JMeter Functions concept.

Comment: I have given space between new and bufferedReader and it works, Thanks for pointing out the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code, and below is the updated code, it works for me, I changed the first line of code, given space between new and BufferedReader.

```
BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("F:/url.txt"));
int counter = 1;
content = fileReader.readLine();
while ((nextLine = fileReader.readLine()) != null)
{
content = content + "\n" + nextLine;
counter++;
}
vars.put("content",content);
log.info(content);
```